# Conditional numpy array modification by the indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have one more question about NumPy)

I want select the some number of the nodes from grid by condition. The purpose is take the nodes that will be closest to circle, and move them to circle boundary (by Ox or Oy - it depends on what distance will be less).

[image]

My implementation:

```
x = np.linspace(0, lx, nx)
y = np.linspace(0, ly, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# one part of condition
distance = R - np.sqrt((X-x0)**2 + (Y-y0)**2)
condition = (distance > 0) & (distance < step)
```

Now I can get (x, y) coordinates of interesting nodes

```
for i, val in np.ndenumerate(X[condition]):
    pass

for j, val in np.ndenumerate(Y[condition]):
    pass
```

Then I should compare x and y (i.e. I need values, not indices) for the resulting nodes, and modify X or Y depending on the result of comparison.
It may be like:

```
# distance_X/distance_Y are the distances to circle boundary by Ox/Oy
for x, y in np.nditer([distance_X[condition], distance_Y[condition]]):
    if x < y:
        # modify X array
    if y < x:
        # modify Y array
```

As you see, I can't just `X[condition] = some_value`

So how can I implement this?

**UPD:**

The complete formulation and the advice of @ecatmur have solved my problem. The solution may be like (similarly for Y):

```
condition_X = condition & (distance_X < distance_Y)
X[condition_X] = (X - distance_X)[condition_X]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your conditions with the `&` operator:

```
X[condition & (distance_X < distance_Y)] = ...
Y[condition & (distance_Y < distance_X)] = ...
```

Comment: Sorry to mislead - I should compare not the coordinates, but distances from node to circle boundary by Ox/Oy (I edited the question).

Comment: Still works the same way; just use `distance_X < distance_Y` as the condition.

Comment: Thanks, you right. But there is one moment that I still can't understand - how can I with using this operation
`X[condition & condition2] = val`
set value, which will be dependent from indices?
`X[condition & condition2] = func(index)`

Comment: @erthalion use vectorised operations e.g. for `x + y` write `X + Y`.  You may want to use `np.select` instead of indexing.